# Is there any way to clear entity cache in a weblogic server without restarting? [for debugging]

Tags: java, debugging, jpa, ejb, weblogic

I am investigating a bug in my application which runs on Weblogic 10.3.4 server. For this investigation, sometimes I need to clear some tables in the database directly (using SQL Navigator). But these changes doesn't reflect immediately in the weblogic server unless I restart it. It is a time consuming task to restart this every time I modify the data in the database.

I was wondering whether there is an easy and quick way to clear the database cache in the weblogic server and force it to reload the modified data. I think if I add a ejb which calls the flush method related to every entity and if I call that method, it will do this task.
 But do you have any suggestion or any other way to do this task, may be by changing a weblogic server setting?
Is there any one method call we can do for forcing flushing of all the entities in current container?

Comment: Which JPA provider are you using?  JPA 1.0 had an EntityManager.clear() api which would dereference all managed entities in the current EntityManager, but this would not clear the shared cache if you are using a provider that had one.  OpenJPA was the default, but it also shipped with EclipseLink that could be enabled for JPA 2.0 support

Comment: If it is EclipseLink, it ships with MBeans you can use described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Integrating_EclipseLink_with_an_Application_Server_(ELUG)#How_to_Integrate_JMX

Comment: @Chris JPA provider is EclipseLink. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA 2.0 has a Cache API that allows you to clear the cache (evictAll).

EclipseLink also has its own API previous the JPA 2.0.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Cache_API